# How to filter out elements based on many-to-many relation to other table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have Adventures class, Hashtag class and relation class HashtagAdventure. What I want to do is to get all adventures that have at least one hashtag from a set that is provided by user.

```js
@Table
export class HashtagAdventure extends Model<HashtagAdventure> {
    @AllowNull(false)
    @ForeignKey(() => Hashtag)
    @Column
    hashtagId: string;

    @AllowNull(false)
    @ForeignKey(() => Adventure)
    @Column
    adventureId: string;
}


@Table
export class Hashtag extends Model<Hashtag> {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column(DataType.STRING)
    id: string;

    @Column(DataType.TEXT)
    text: string;

    @BelongsToMany(() => Adventure, () => HashtagAdventure)
    adventures: Adventure[];
}

@Table
export class Adventure extends Model<Adventure> {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column(DataType.STRING)
    id: string;

    @BelongsToMany(() => Hashtag, () => HashtagAdventure)
    hashtags: Hashtag[];
}
```

Consider an example:

MyAdventure [#awesome, #great]

OtherAdventure [#cool]

BoringAdvenure [#boring]

---

user query: [#awesome, #cool]

---

expected output:

MyAdventure [#awesome, #great]

OtherAdventure [#cool]

---

the best I've acheived so far by playing with queries (like through in include):

MyAdventure [#awesome]

OtherAdventure [#cool]

BoringAdvenure []